# mxGraph javascript Grapheditor save button is greyed out - Can i use PHP to save graph xml file and image?

Tags: mxgraph

I've cloned mxGraph from https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph. 
I've pointed my browser to http://localhost/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/

Now I can create graphs, however I cannot save them as both "Save" and "Save as..." is grey color.

[image]

1. How can I enable save?
2. Can I use PHP to save the image and XML so I can get and unique ID that I can save in a MySQL database table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mxGraph -Save functionality not working locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664578/mxgraph-save-functionality-not-working-locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the *save* option as below.

```
mxUtils.post(OPEN_URL, '', mxUtils.bind(this, function(req)
                {
                    var enabled = req.getStatus() != 404;
                    this.actions.get('open').setEnabled(enabled || Graph.fileSupport);
                    this.actions.get('import').setEnabled(enabled || Graph.fileSupport);
                    this.actions.get('save').setEnabled(true)
                    this.actions.get('saveAs').setEnabled(true);
                    this.actions.get('export').setEnabled(enabled);
                }));
```

**1.Save the XML in Local Storage:**

Enable local storage

```
Editor.useLocalStorage = true
```

then, you can get the XML file from

```
var temp = localStorage[filename.xml];
```

**2.Get the XML dynamically:**

Please refer the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899522)