# mxGraph - Displaying a diagram by loading a XML

Tags: javascript, php, mxgraph

With the help of [How to get the XML from mxGrpah diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899522) able to get the dynamic XML from the graph editor.
Now, I need to display the diagram by loading a XML (reverse algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, similarly to [How to get the XML from mxGrpah diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899522/how-to-get-the-xml-from-mxgrpah-diagram) answer, it is not again clear to me how to get the `graph` object in which the whole graph is saved so I propose the following workaround:

**1) Get the reference of the original graph object into your index.html code**

**i**. Add a global variable into index.html to get the reference of the `graph` object

```
var universalGraph;
```

**ii.**  Go into a .js file where the `graph` object has already been created (for example go to **js/view/mxGraphView** on `installListeners` function and **assign the instance of the graph object to your global accessible reference**

```
mxGraphView.prototype.installListeners = function(){
var graph = this.graph;
var container = graph.container;
universalGraph = graph; //this way, you will have access from .index.html to the graph object and you will be able to import the xml as shown in the example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664578/mxgraph-save-functionality-not-working-locally/56735153#56735153
```

As you will see, now the solution with the global `Graph.xml` was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899522) is redundant since now this way you will have always access into the `graph` object :) .

**2) Since you have now the `graph` object, you can use it for any purpose you wany (export/import the xml state)**

**EDIT**

I post also an example of how you should upload the xml in `index.html`

```
function uploadXML(){
        let xml = '<thexml_you_got_from_the_export><thexml_you_got_from_the_export/>';
        let doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
        let codec = new mxCodec(doc);
        codec.decode(doc.documentElement, universalGraph.getModel());
        let elt = doc.documentElement.firstChild;
        let cells = [];
        while (elt != null)
        {
            let cell = codec.decode(elt)
            if(cell != undefined){
                if(cell.id != undefined && cell.parent != undefined && (cell.id == cell.parent)){
                    elt = elt.nextSibling;
                    continue;
                }
                cells.push(cell);
            }
            elt = elt.nextSibling;
        }
        universalGraph.addCells(cells);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @NickAth ! 
I can upload my own xml with your example but how can i have current xml to export it please ?This solution works : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899522/how-to-get-the-xml-from-mxgrpah-diagram but click event is not good for my project.

Comment: i changed listener to mouseMove , it works but im not sure if it is the best way to do it

Comment: What exactly you want to do? When you want your xml to be exported?

Comment: I have a custom export button to export xml to database.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me @NickAth, I keep getting duplicate ID error

Answer (score 4):

Many thanks @NickAth, Also, I tried my own analysis found that the following solution is working fine.

```
var xml = {xml};
var ui = new EditorUi(new Editor());
var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
ui.editor.setGraphXml(doc.documentElement);
```

Comment: Great! Just have in mind that this way you use another EditorUI different from the example's, now you also have access to the graph object using `ui.editor.graph` :)