# mxGraph - Retain the original shape color

Tags: javascript, php, mxgraph

**Scenario:**

1. Create Diagram:

[image: mxGrpah editor original color]
After completed the drawing of diagram,I am getting mxGrpah XML nodes from graph and storing in to the database.

2. Edit Diagram:

User can view/edit the existing diagram, here I'm retrieving all XML nodes from database, combined and binding to the graph. ***While loading the page all the shape colors are showing in to blue***

[image: mxGrpah editor color changed]

**Question:**

I have not change any style attributes, also not sure about why it's displaying in blue color. Is there any workaround to retain the original color?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075352/mxgraph-displaying-a-diagram-by-loading-a-xml/57075697#57075697 I suspect it has to do with what I mentioned in the comment under your answer

Comment: @NickAth, Awesome! Issue cause could be var ui = new EditorUi(new Editor()); because it's creating a new editor. I tried with your solution and works well.

Comment: you could change the accepted answer if it helped you :)